# Refactor Switch in Groovy

Tags: groovy, switch-statement, refactoring

I have this method:

```
void schedule(){
switch (schedule.getType()) {
                case MANUAL:
                    scheduleManual();
                    break;
                case AUTO:
                    scheduleAuto();
                    break;
                case NONE:
                    scheduleNone();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
}
```

And I'd like to know if there's a better design to have this instead of a switch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void schedule(){
    def method = 'schedule' + schedule.getType().toString().toLowerCase().capitalize()
    this."$method"()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `methodMissing()` magic:

```
enum Type {MANUAL, AUTO, NONE}

schedule = Type.AUTO

def methodMissing(String name, args){
  if( name in Type.values()*.toString() )
    this."schedule${name.toLowerCase().capitalize()}"()
}

void schedule(){
  this."$schedule"()
}

void scheduleManual(){ println "calling scheduleManual" }
void scheduleAuto(){ println "calling scheduleAuto" }

schedule()
```